# Software for deleting music from directory rather than playlist

Tags: windows, music, audio, file-management

My dad has 700+ MP3 and WMA files on a memory stick which he sticks into his truck's radio system, now there are a bunch of songs he wants deleted however the radio system just reveals a track number (eg. 5/700).

The problem with me is that because I'm the computer user he expects me to do it, in the past I would just play one song after another waiting for him to tell me if it's one that he wants to keep or not, however this can take hours.

Now I'm looking for some software for Windows which I can load all the songs into it and have my dad go though them all himself and clicking one button to delete the song from the computer rather than the playlist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Banshee](http://banshee.fm/) for Linux has a "Delete from Drive" function in its right-click menu which works well.

[image: Screenshot]

Banshee is also available for Windows and OS X.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in **Windows Media Player**. To do this:

1. Right click on the song.
2. Click `Delete`
3. Select `Delete from library and my computer`
4. Click `OK`. You can select `Don't show this message again` to skip this dialogue box in future.

[image: Delete from library and my computer]

Answer (score 1):

You can also delete songs on [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) for Windows:

[image: foobar2000 screenshot]